# Graceful Win32 windowless process termination

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I am working on a console application, written in C#, where I trigger [`Application.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=net-5.0) to manage the system tray. The application itself is window-less.

[image: Screenshot of the application configuration in Visual Studio]

Here's the challenge I am encountering - when the user closes the application, I need to do cleanup, and make sure that I remove the application icon from the system tray. Easy enough to do when I have a console window attached and allocated since I can use [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler).

However, the problems start when I do not have a console window allocated and attached (since the application runs like that most of the time). I want to **gracefully** terminate the process from another process, so that I can call [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) in my application and do the cleanup. But, all the guidance that I find on doing that for Windows is through sending `WM_CLOSE` messages, which would not apply since I do not have any windows available for the application.

So, considering that the application in question is launched with [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), I have the process ID, handle, and main thread ID.

**Question**: is there a way for me to gracefully tell the other application to terminate without calling [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) (which would not give any leeway to do any cleanup)?

I am thinking I might need to implement a named pipe so that I can communicate between the client application and the "server" in this case, but it feels like overkill for having a way to nicely ask the process to wrap things up.

Comment: What we used to do is have process1 pass its handle to process2 when it starts it. Then process2 can use [GetExitCodeProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) to figure out if the parent has exited. You could also wait on the parent process instead of polling if that's a better fit for your app.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do cleanup if you do not set it up. You need either use message (like but not necessary `WM_CLOSE`) or implement your own communication.

Comment: Why not just run a hidden window to receive messages. I thought you needed a window to run in the notification area (aka the _System Tray_). How does your icon get messages without a window

Comment: If you succeeded to place an icon into the shell notification area, then clearly you must have supplied a valid `HWND` for [NOTIFYICONDATAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataw). What keeps you from using that window for purposes of communication?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I think conceptually that makes sense, however the challenge is also in the fact that the parent process might still be running. I'd just like to terminate the process gracefully _from _ the parent.

Comment: @Flydog57 I just run a message loop with `Application.Run()`. I might need to fire up Spy++ to see if there is a handle generated behind the scenes.

Comment: @IInspectable I am using the Windows Forms API within a console application, so there very well may be a hidden window. I will have to check.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky Yeah, if you want to be able to tell the child to shut down and keep the parent running you need a bit more. The event idea suggested in the answer should work. We did something like that for a child->parent "Sucessfully running" handshake but it works both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you should implement own method of communication. IMHO, simplest way is using named event. Console application creates named event and sometimes checks it. External application sets event in case to exit first application.
This method works for Windows only.

Comment: A named [`EventWaitHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle?view=netstandard-2.0) can also be used for operating systems other than Windows.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it's the only reliable way that I implemented that worked correctly.